# Subscribing to a static data change Angular 2 TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, angular2-services

I have an object that gets updated from various locations.  I'd like to subscribe to it.
Problem is - Item's are not being generated.

[image]

And I'm subscribing to it that way:
[image]

I'm trying to get the subscriber to know when data on my object (AppData.SelectedUser.assets) changes.  Any suggestions?

I'd greatly appreciate some help on this manner (Kinda new to Angular).

Comment: "Item's are not being generated." - What do you mean? Is this subscribe block running? Have you tried debugging it?

Comment: Are you asking how to set it up so that as the object changes, you subscribe to it so you know the new value?

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel exactly!!  Updated my question as per your comment

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use some sort of `Subject` to hold onto the value and push new values onto it. Specifically, you'll want to use a `BehaviorSubject` probably.

It looks like the property `assets` and method `getAssets` are in the same class. You'll want to have a new private variable in that class that is the `Subject` to hold onto the assets as time changes (whenever a change is made to assets you'll push another value on your subject). You can then simply return your subject as an observable in your `getAssets` method.

There are tons of examples on StackOverflow and across Google of doing just this. One such example can be found [at this blog](https://blog.angular-university.io/how-to-build-angular2-apps-using-rxjs-observable-data-services-pitfalls-to-avoid/).

Comment: So the reason observable won't work is  because I keep changing my Assets array and not just adding/subtracting from it?

Comment: Yeah, if you made changes directly to the object (in this case array) they would propagate throughout the app. It isn't ideal in most cases to modify the original object behind the scenes because some code that used those properties (items in this case) will not know that it was changed and will not trigger code that needs to run.

Comment: If you don't want to broadcast changes as they are made, there really is no reason to use an observable in this case.

Comment: However, what I really am trying to achieve is to load the static data while I wait for the http.get call to be loaded (something that can take 0.5-10 seconds, or never).

Comment: In that case then yeah, go take a look at that blog post

Comment: Much appreciated. If that works, I'll mark that as the answer.  Thanks!

Comment: I ended up using "startWith" which will do exactly what I wanted.  That being said, YOUR answer did provide lots of information.